# Does not show the video on the screen cv2

Tags: python, opencv, webcam

What is the problem ?
It does not give an error. Keeps working until it freezes

My camera lights up but does not show the video on the screen

```
#my cam "0"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
frame = None
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here screen

[image]

Comment: try to print the frame and check what is getting printed.

Comment: its array not empty

Comment: try to use cv2.VideoCapture(-1) inplace of cv2.VideoCapture(0)

Comment: cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-2b5g8ysb\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Comment: try to use cv2.VideoCapture(1)

Comment: VideoCapture not problem 0 working, cam opening but not show on screen

Comment: Is your webcam working with other applications ?

Comment: yes, it works fine.

Comment: it's got 2 more fail to. Neither picture opening nor video playing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the cv2.imshow() does not render without cv2.waitkey()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44854699/why-does-the-cv2-imshow-does-not-render-without-cv2-waitkey)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a `cv2.waitKey` call to set the delay time for each frame. Currently your code is like *0 milliseconds per frames*, which is causing the problem.

Try:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
frame = None
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1) # 1 millisecond per frame
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Or, you could make the closing process easier by adding this `if` statement:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
frame = None
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Where the camera would close when you press the q key.